# Truncated sudoers file, no user can edit it now

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

So, somehow one of the guys on my team messed up the sudoers file on a couple of VMs (all Ubuntu 18.04).

The files were truncated and the only line in them is: 

`nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD= ALL`

Which, fine, `su` to the `nagios` user and fix the sudoers file, except the `nagios` user has no password assigned, and there is no root password defined. So that won't work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `pkexec visudo` (run from the account of a member of the `sudo` group) might be worth a try. See for example [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file)

Comment: Yeah, I was hopeful for this one too, but alas, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Can you (if reasonably practical) start the VMs using a (virtual) external storage device? A medium with a live system will allow you to mount the filesystem and edit the sudoers file as root without needing that file for permissions, since the live system grants the permissions.